# Unable to set userName using set state in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        userName: 'yfky',
        length: 10
    };
    onClickHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({userName : event.target.value})
    };

    calculate = () => {
      // const len = this.userName.length
      console.log(this.userName);
      this.setState({length: this.userName.length})
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
        onChange={(event) => this.onClickHandler(event)} />
        <button onClick={this.calculate}></button>
     {this.length}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
calculate = () => {
  // const len = this.userName.length
  console.log(this.userName);
  this.setState({length: this.userName.length})
}
```

You are saving userName and length in the `state` object.

So you have to do `this.state` to access state object

```
calculate = () => {
  // const len = this.userName.length
  console.log(this.state.userName);
  this.setState({length: this.state.userName.length})
}
```